# Where can I find tortoisehg windows installer checksum?

Tags: tortoisehg

I downloaded tortoisehg-5.9.3-x64.msi from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/tortoisehg/windows/.  The file is not digitally signed.
Does anyone know where can I find the checksum (md5, sha256 or ect.) for that file?

Comment: You might be able to find out by asking at https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues